# External shop embedded in an iframe uses cookies -- Is is possible if the user blocks third party cookies?

Tags: iframe, cookies

Assume you have to integrate a web shop into our own web site using an iframe. The other shop uses cookies and cannot operate if its cookies are blocked.

**What if a user blocks 3rd party cookies?**

If the user uses Internet Explorer, setting [P3P Headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P3P) can solve the problem. However, P3P is not supported by other major browsers.

So, after some research and experiments, I come to the realization that it is not possible to make it work on all other browsers. (Though I could only test with Firefox and Chrome.)

For my understanding, Mozilla has enforced the third-party cookie settings in a strict sense since 2013: http://webpolicy.org/2013/02/22/the-new-firefox-cookie-policy/

Many articles about third-party cookies in iframes were written before 2013. I don't think they are still valid. Some sources claim that you have at least access to existing cookies. According to my experiments, even that is no longer the case.

**Are my conclusions correct:**

- Is it true that it is not longer possible to work around the browser settings?
- In other words, is the recommended solution just to tell the user to allow 3rd-party cookies?

Should I be wrong, I will be glad to hear that. :-)

I have to clarify that it is OK if the solution involves some changes in the web shop that needs to be integrated. So you can assume that the operators of the shops will help you (unless it takes unrealistic time and resources, of course).

---

Side note: I found some possible alternatives, but they are quiet expensive to implement and operate. For example, you could redirect all traffic to the external shop through a proxy server on the same domain (so the cookies become first-party again). Another solution that I read was to replace cookies by local storage but that is easier said than done.

---

If you want to reproduce the problem, here is a minimal example to start with (using www.mercateo.co.uk):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-15">
<title></title></head><body><h1></h1>

<p>Begin iframe</p>

<iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" align="left" scrolling="auto" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" id="iframe" src="http://www.mercateo.co.uk/basket/view?cookieTest=true" style="height: 586px;"></iframe>

<p>End iframe</p>
</body></html>
```

If third-party cookies are blocked, it will redirect you to an error page showing "Your browser does not accept cookies". Tested on Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: It's to be expected. The browser has no way of knowing that iframe #1 is an external useful app, while iframes #2 through #99999 are useless spam for which cookies should be blocked.

Comment: @MarcB But some time ago, workarounds existed, didn't they? From what I read, Mozilla considered it a security and privacy issue and blocked all those attempts to bypass the user settings. (At least that is what I understand so far.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no general solution that works for every browser. There are workarounds for IE and Safari, but not for Firefox and Chrome.

Let us break it down:

**1. Internet Explorer**

Yes, it is possible to set 3rd party cookies using the [P3P protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P3P) (Platform for Privacy Preferences Project).

To implement it, the shop that is embedded in the iframe can set a "P3P HTTP response header, for example:

```
P3P: CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTR STP IND DEM"
```

CP stands for "compact policy". The content of the "CP" is described in the [P3P specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/CR-P3P-20001215/#compact_policy_vocabulary)). You also need to deploy a Full P3P Privacy Policy as described [in this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms537341(v=vs.85).aspx)

It is controversial, as the browser cannot verify the information is correct. It has to trust the sender. Quote from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P3P#Criticisms):

> A key problem that occurs with the use of P3P is that there is a lack of enforcement. Thus, promises made to users of P3P can go unfulfilled. Though by using P3P a company/website makes a promise of privacy and of the use of gathered data to the site’s users, there are no real legal ramifications if the company decides to use the information for other functions.

As a consequence, no other major browser implements P3P.

**2. Safari (including iOS devices)**

Yes, it is possible to access and modify 3rd party cookies. Although, in general, Safari does not allow you to set 3rd party cookies, it permits the access to already existing 3rd party cookies.

Note that Safari blocks 3rd party cookies by default. In Firefox and Chrome, the user has to actively change the browser's cookie settings.

**3. Firefox and Chrome**

No, if the user decides to block 3rd party cookies, you cannot work around it.

These two browsers respects the user's cookie settings. In the end, it is always a trade-off between privacy and convenience.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do to bypass this problem, and based on your statement that it is possible to ask for changes in the shop, is to create a kind of a "bridge" between the iframe app and your wrapping page.  Inter frame communication is supported on all major browsers so there is no technical gap to solve here.

So the IFrame app would "ask you" to set cookies for it, since you are the main domain it will be on 1st party which will work, and every time the shop's iframe loads it will have to ask you for the cookies in order to be able to identify the user.  This is possible and not technically very difficult, but will require the app to work AJAX based instead of page based (which is always better IMO because it means you are separating view from data).